# Wordpress using .NET?

Tags: .net, wordpress, open-source, plugins

Have anyone seen or tried Wordpress.NET?

I read an [article](http://www.blogsdna.com/2546/wordpress-net-a-net-version-of-php-based-wordpress-271.htm) about it before, but it is now [nowhere to be found](http://wordpress.codeplex.com/).

Any similar open source where I could get one?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps Wordpress's PHP source can be compiled using [Phalanger, the PHP for .NET compiler](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/)?  That would make more sense long term than translating the WordPress sources into something else and then compiling for .NET.

Comment: There is detailed guide how to run WordPress on .NET using Phalanger http://phpcompiler.net/blog/2011/wordpress-on-net-4-0